# Auto hide rows and columns based on value in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

I'm trying to write a spreadsheet that will hide the majority of rows and about half the columns when the value of `A1=blank`. Rows will be based on properties, with 14 rows per property (first row will have the main information; the rest will contain various types of inspections). Columns will be random information about the property, including a bunch of dates.

The goal is that the spreadsheet would be a summary of data when `A1=blank`, but very detailed information about the property would open up when `A1=PropertyName`. The rest of the rows for the other properties besides the main row would remain hidden.

So, if `A1=PropertyName`, then I'd like the rows for that property and columns to be unhidden.

I tried various methods I found via Google, but I have very basic understanding of VBA, so I can't get those methods to work. Also, I've only found ways to hide rows and columns separately (which I wasn't able to get working anyway), and I don't have the experience to know how to combine them.

If anyone can give me a start in the right direction, I'm sure I can use it to make the rest of it work. If you need any clarification on anything I've said, please ask. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Do the size of the individual ranges change?  Will selecting Property A always show you the same set of rows and columns?

Comment: The way I envision it, selecting Property A would expand the 13 hidden rows and all of the hidden columns so that every hidden detail is unhidden.

The same would be true for Property B, C, etc.

I hope I understood your question.