# Hide Columns when in a row in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not that much expert in using Excel. I have a list of rows and cols in my excel.

[image]

I have a table list like this. I have kept the first column as fixed in Excel.

Now I am trying to hide the Col1 group when the user scrolls on row 1 (C) and 
Hide Col2 Group when the user scrolls on row2(C++)
Hide Col1 group and Col3 group when the user scrolls on row 3(Java)

How to achieve this in Excel 2003.

Comment: It is too difficult to implement using the Window Scroll as the trigger.  You could use the Worksheet Selection Change Even, Command Buttons  or Hyperlinks to switch views.  Checkout my post from last week.  [Working With Custom Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754928/auto-hide-rows-and-columns-based-on-value-in-specific-cell/37756039#37756039)

Comment: It seems a bit strange to hide those columns, because even when you scroll there will be multiple rows visible, and then the user cannot see the values that are of interest to those rows. Can you explain why you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Thomas Inzina, using `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and `select case` following code achieves your requirements. But I wont appreciate this way of creating UI in Excel.
(Put this code in "Sheet" not in Module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Select Case Target.Row
    Case Is = 2
        Columns("B:C").Hidden = True
    Case Is = 3
        Columns("D:E").Hidden = True
    Case Is = 4
        Columns("F:G").Hidden = True
    Case Else
End Select
End Sub
```

[image]